# Print PDF with google cloud print [Android]

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-print

can anyone point me some study material on how to print a PDF on Android, using Google Cloud Print or example, I've already studied [this](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html)  documentation, but not there is material on how I can do this integration.